# volunteers not showing in widget

Tags: civivolunteer

I am using a fresh install of civivolunteer on wordpress 4.7.5.
Everything seems to work, except online registration's don't show in assign volunteers!
The activities are logged in the database, because I can see the registrations in a volunteer report. But the screen 'assign volunteers' is blanc.
Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You don't mention if the logged in user trying to assign a volunteer is in a particular Wordpress role. Do they have access to CiviCRM?

Comment: found the issue; users activity are logged in status Completed; should be scheduled; is this a bug, or am i doing someting wrong?

Comment: You are referring to "online registrations" but not saying how volunteers are being registered. If volunteers sign themselves up using the public form (e.g., civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/opportunities), the activities are created in either Available or Scheduled status. How are volunteers being registered?

Comment: using the public form; activities are in completed status

Comment: so in my case, the activities are created in completed status; If i manually change the status into scheduled, they appear

Comment: How can i solve this? Use civirule? Please help..

Comment: I have the same issue. I've created a volunteer project through an event form and defined several roles. If a person registers to any role and any time, it is shown. However, if he specifies a role and a shift, he is not shown because the activity is recorded as complete. If I change it to scheduled, the person is shown in the widget. CiviCRM 5.10.4, CiviVolunteer 4.7.31-2.3.1